# Can I create music sheets with LaTeX?

Tags: music

If so, how? Do I need any additional software?

Comment: In case the answer is no, this may be useful: http://vexflow.com/

Comment: I have created some examples you might be interested in: http://martin-thoma.com/how-to-write-music-with-latex/ - if somebody knows some more complex ones or a page like TeXample, please let me know!

Comment: There's another package `abc`, see comparison here [Set music in LaTeX with ABC or LilyPond? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37345/set-music-in-latex-with-abc-or-lilypond?rq=1)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I'd instead use [LilyPond](http://lilypond.org/), which, though not based on TeX at all, has similar goals of human-readable plain-text source files and beautiful, customizable output.

Comment: Actually, Lilypond was originally based on TeX, at least partly, but now it's not the case any more.

Comment: @Arthur: that's news to me. (Seriously. The last time I used Lilypond was close to 6 years ago, and back then it was based on TeX. I wonder what made them switch.)

Comment: Now it's mostly written in C++ with a Scheme interface to control many aspects of the typesetting process.  There also are bits and pieces in Python.

Answer (score 24):

There's also [MusiXTeX](https://icking-music-archive.org/software/htdocs/) or old site https://icking-music-archive.org/software/indexmt6-2012-12.html for the actual typesetting ([CTAN](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=musixtex)). A bit of searching turned up [this page](http://noteedit.berlios.de/doc/musixtex_export_appendix.html) about exporting from LilyPond to MusiXTeX.

Comment: Hi! The link to "this page" looks obsolete.

Answer (score 20):

In addition to MusiXTeX, there's also [GregorioTeX](http://gregorio-project.github.io/gregoriotex/) for gregorian chant.  It's apparently very well suited to typesetting this particular type of scores, and is actively maintained.

Answer (score 16):

Lilypond provides a tool called lilypond-book for creating LaTeX documents with embedded music pieces inside.  The embedding works via images, and baselines are not considered.  So if you want to display a clef in the middle of a line, it will only be nicely aligned vertically with the rest of the line after you have tweaked its vertical position using additional LaTeX code.

If you don't want to create a document, but rather music sheets on their own, Lilypond wins hands down in user friendliness.  I am considered quite unanimously as a TeX wizard and would no longer think of using the TeX-based approaches for typesetting music.

With regard to its implementation: I think Lilypond has always been C++, has gained some Scheme innards rather early, but used TeX as its typesetting backend internally for quite a long time.  However, its current mode of operation is to write PostScript files directly as main output (PDF generation works internally by using Ghostscript on those).  As a result, utf-8 characters work rather transparently if the font has them.  TeX's track record in that area, in comparison, is less than fabulous although in the last years, a few TeX engines (XeTeX, LuaTeX) that can work with larger character sets than 8bit have been developed.

Answer (score 15):

I'd go for Lilypond, myself (see Ben Alpert's answer), but note that there's a [TeX FAQ page of discussion about the alternatives](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-music)

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that all these answers have been a long time.
I think they are wonderful tools but I have discovered **a great summary on CTAN** here: http://tug.ctan.org/info/latex4musicians/latex4musicians.pdf.
This is a **more modern** version with TeX Live > 2018, which offers amazing functions.

> **Excerpt from the document**:
>
> - This guide shows how to create LATEX documents that include
>   several kinds of music elements, from very simple to quite complex.
>   Music features may consist of music symbols, song lyrics, guitar chords
>   diagrams, lead sheets, music excerpts, guitar tablatures, multi-page
>   scores.
> - Music can be produced directly by TEX and LATEX using packages,
>   and also by external scorewriters. Major packages and programs are
>   listed and briefly described, providing ready-to-use examples.

This should be gospel for LaTeX and music lovers!