# Set music in LaTeX with ABC or LilyPond?

Tags: music, lilypond

I’ll give a tutorial, “LaTeX for musicians”, in the next year and certainly I want the to show how to include music in their texts. I’m a musician myself but I never used LaTeX to typeset music.

I found two ways to include music in a LaTeX document (plus: integrate music as image) and I want to share my thoughts and ask for some help (see below). First, let's take a more detailed look at both ways:

### ABC

**Code**

```
% file abc.tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{abc}

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{abc}[name=c-dur]
X: 1 % start of header
K: C % scale: C major
"Text"C4 G4 | (3FED c4 G2 |
\end{abc}
\end{document}
```

**Compile**

```
pdflatex --shell-escape abc.tex
```

**Output**

[image: ABC output]

### LilyPond

**Code**

```
% file lp.lytex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
Text
\begin[staffsize=12]{lilypond}
\relative c' {
  c2^"Text" g'2 \times 2/3 { f8 e d } c'2 g4
}
\end{lilypond}
\end{document}
```

**Compile**

```
lilypond-book --output=out-dir --pdf lp.lytex
cd out-dir
pdflatex lp.tex
```

**Output**

[image: LilyPond output]

### Comparison

Now let’s talk about the pros and cons.

- The **ABC** workflow is much **easier** than the one of LilyPond and it simply needs a call of `pdflatex`. For this it’s preferable for the students of the tutorial since most of them aren't computer geeks.
- The **ABC syntax** seems to bee **easier** at a first glance.
- **LilyPond** uses the **right font** i.e. the font of the LaTeX document.
- **`abc.sty`** always produces a ***display style* image**, i.e., it starts a new line and centers it’s content. Furthermore there seems to be now option to shorten the line that they fit just the typed notes and not span the whole `\linewidth` (workaround: set `width=0.5\abcwidth`).
- As far as I can see **LilyPond** is **more flexible** in the number of ways to typeset music (*inline*, *display style*, …) and the possibilities of typesetting in general.
- The **LilyPond music font looks better** except the fat bar lines.

### Questions

<sup>The numbers are not to give an order. I numbered the questions to make it easy to answer the …</sup>

1. Which way would you prefer to use? Which one do you suggest for students how a not very good in using computers?
2. I wonder if it will be possible to create a package that integrates LilyPond in the same way that `abc.sty` does width ABC notation
3. Can one change the font of the ABC output so that it matches the LaTeX main font?
4. Is there a way to make ABC find a good line length for the given number of notes?
5. Can one change the width of LilyPonds bar lines?

### Conclusion

I’d prefer to use (and teach) the LilyPond way but I fear the compilation workflow would scare the students. So if question 2 could be solved it would be great :-)

<sub>I hope you understand what I want since my english may be not the best. Please ask if something is not clear …</sub>

Comment: [@PauloCereda](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda) recently blogged about this.  You can read it [here](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/sheet-music-with-lilypond-and-frescobaldi/)

Comment: @percusse: Thank you for this info but this bolg doesn’t say anithing abut a LaTeX integration :-(

Comment: For ABC you did include the package with `\usepackage{abc}`. How come you don't include any package for the lilypond? I am asking, because i couldn't find the lilypond package myself.

Comment: @71GA: (As far as I remeber …) You don’t need a package but you must precompile the document with `lilypond-book` before you can process it with `pdflatex`. The precompiling looks for the `{lilypond}` environment. Crates the score as an image and replaces the environment in the precomiled `tex` file with commands to include the image. Just process the above example to see how it works.

Comment: Both ways are very valid. But have you also considered musixtex?

Comment: I wonder if you could use `arara` to help with LaTeX integration?  Since @PauloCereda is the author of `arara` and the LilyPond blog post, maybe he would know if this is possible (or even a valid idea).

Comment: I just saw this question and its answer using `arara`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111055/6510.  I think it's basically what I was suggesting.  Does it help you with reducing the LilyPond workflow?

Comment: My wife is a musician too, and back when I compared option to typeset music, `LilyPond` was the clear winner by far. It's output is/was way above anything else you could find in the industry, including (very) expensive commercial solutions like Sybelius.

Comment: If arara isn't your thing and you're worried about compilation workflow, you could always try throwing yet another tool (Make) at them and do something like this: https://gist.github.com/SamWhited/7902221

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not possible to use the same font as the document with ABC, for inherent limitations of the `abcm2ps` program. However, it's quite a long time since I don't update it and things might have changed (I'll take a look).

It should be easy to add "inline" versions of the music snippet inclusion, which is not there because the package was intended for inclusion of complete tunes.

Integration with LilyPond in the same way is not as easy. I have some "kind-of-working" code. A major hindrance is the difficulty of passing LilyPond parameters and directives from the TeX side (with lilypond-book it's the other way around).

Since there seems to be interest in this topic, I'll try and develop the code. For now, the following code

```
\begin{filecontents*}{testlily.ly}
\version "2.13.38" 

\include "config.ly" 

\relative c'' { 
c d e c 
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{testlily3.ly}
\version "2.13.38" 

\include "config.ly" 

\relative c' {
  c2^"Text" g'2 \times 2/3 { f8 e d } c'2 g4
}

\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[draft]{article} 
\usepackage[final]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[MacOSX,between-system-space=3]{lilypond} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Test: integrating \LaTeX{} and LilyPond. 

\lilypondfile{testlily} 

Not too bad, isn't it? 

\lipsum[2] 

\lilypondfile{testlily3} 

\end{document}
```

will produce the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this and sory for the delayed answer. Could you tell me where I can find `lilypond.sty`? I found onw at [github](https://github.com/Stemby/latex-lilypond/downloads) but that needs a pythonscript …

Comment: @Tobi That's a private package I'm experimenting with.

Comment: Could show me your code? I thought about building an onw package but I guess it’s not nessescary that we both do the same jobe … (You may send an e-mail to the address given in my profile)

Comment: @Tobi Sorry, but there isn't any address there.

Comment: Thas strange. I can see it if I open my profile. Here ist is: `tobias_weh{at}arcor{dot}de`

Comment: @Tobi Some information on the profile is visible only to the owner (real name and email, for instance).

Comment: Didn’t know that. Sorry …

Comment: @egreg FYI, I'm also interested in this. Will you be sharing your results on github when you have something working?

Comment: But how did you compile it?

Comment: Just another vote for this approach. I have been looking for something like this for **years**. I'd like a copy of lilypond.sty myself as soon as it is ready.

Comment: Are there any updates on this package? Is there any possibility of it being released at all?

Comment: Has this ever been published? Is it on your github?

Comment: @thymaro No, I just did some experiments. Nowadays I'd recommend `lyluatex`

Answer (score 8):

[LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) may be an good for this purpose and the audience you mention. From the [LyX Wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX20#lb):

> Support for LilyPond-Book
>   LyX now supports LilyPond music notation
>   with the lilypond-book module, by direct entry of LilyPond markup in
>   LyX's window and processing through lilypond-book→(pdf)latex. In
>   combination with the new preview inset, you can view the score
>   directly in the LyX window. For more information see LyX's example
>   file `lilypond.lyx`.

Comment: Thank you but I’m not a friend of LyX since it shows some kind of WSIWYG but not the real output (If I understood the programm right) …