# How to run LaTeX and lilypond-book in one command?

Tags: macros, pdftex, latexmk, lilypond

I was wondering if there was any command which would let me create a PDF from a LyTeX source in one step. Currently, I am first executing `lilypond-book`:

```
 lilypond-book --latex-program=pdflatex --pdf --lily-output-dir=./tmp ./thesis.lytex
```

and, when this is done, the usual PDFLaTeX call:

```
pdflatex ./thesis.tex
```

While this works fine, I was wondering if there was a way to execute this as a single command (I would like to create a single typesetting rule for this in TeXworks, but for this, I need to have all this in a single command). I know that I could create a custom shell script for this (in fact, this is what I actually have now). However, I was specifically wondering if there was a 'built-in' solution for this? I was thinking about a solution similar to the LaTeXMK approach, which allows to run BibTeX and LaTeX and a few other tools from within the same command, taking care of the right order of calling the different programs, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let my try to solve your issue using [`arara`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara)

If you hear `arara` the first time here a small abstract:

*`arara` allows the specification of the compilation steps from the main document*

This small sentence isn't able to describe the whole power of the tool. Therefor you can have a look at the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara) or the short intro at the homepage: [Homepage `arara`](http://cereda.github.io/arara/)

The current stable version of `arara` is available at CTAN and it's part of TeX Live/MacTeX. If you are using MikTeX, you have to install `arara`. This is also explained in the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara).

The following description expect two points:

1. You have installed `lilypond` (I know you have `;-)`)
2. You get the following output in the terminal if you call `arara`:

---

```bsh
marco@imac:~/Desktop/test$arara
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

arara 3.0 - The cool TeX automation tool
Copyright (c) 2012, Paulo Roberto Massa Cereda
All rights reserved.

usage: arara [file [--log] [--verbose] [--timeout N] [--language L] |
             --help | --version]
 -h,--help             print the help message
 -L,--language <arg>   set the application language
 -l,--log              generate a log output
 -t,--timeout <arg>    set the execution timeout (in milliseconds)
 -v,--verbose          print the command output
 -V,--version          print the application version
```

---

Now we can start. `arara` provides a lot of rules but not for `lilypond`. However writing a rule is nearly simple. The following rule can be taken as a starting point. Of course you can use the rule without any changes. Save the file as `lilypond.yaml` (the extension is important).

**`lilypond.yaml`**

```yaml
!config
# Mainfile rule for arara
# author: Marco Daniel
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: lilypond
name: Lilypond
command: <arara> lilypond-book @{format} @{options} @{output} "@{file}"
arguments:
- identifier: format
  flag: <arara> --format=@{parameters.latex-programm}
  default: <arara> --format=latex
- identifier: options
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
- identifier: output
  flag: <arara> --output=@{parameters.output}
```

Next step is the new file extension `lytex`. `arara` supports `tex`, `dtx`, `ltx` but not yours. So you must tell `arara` to use a new extension. This can be done in a file named `araraconfig.yaml` which **must** be saved in your home directory. There you can add a path for the new rule and the new extension. In my System it looks like:

**`araraconfig.yaml`**

```yaml
!config
# Config file to use texmfhome as search path
# author: Marco Daniel
# requires arara 3.0+
paths:
- /Users/marco/Library/texmf/scripts/arara/rules

filetypes:
- extension: lytex
  pattern: ^(\s)*%\s+
```

Related to this configuration file you can save the provided rule in the folder

```bsh
/Users/marco/Library/texmf/scripts/arara/rules
```

Do this. As you can see the filetype with a search pattern is also specified. You can read more about this in the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara).

---

Now let us take an example. I saved the file as `test.lytex`:

**`test.lytex`**

```
% arara: lilypond
% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ test.tex ] }
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{lilypond}[staffsize=12]
\relative c' {
  c2^"Text" g'2 \times 2/3 { f8 e d } c'2 g4
}
\end{lilypond}
\end{document}
```

After calling `arara`

```bsh
marco@imac:~/Desktop/test$arara test.lytex
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running Lilypond... SUCCESS
Running PDFLaTeX... SUCCESS
```

I get the following output:

[image]

Comment: Hello and thank you for the effort, this is indeed very nice. However, I just can't figure out two things: (1) how can I put the config file to another place than my home folder? It looks very silly there; and (2) how can I add additional lilypond-book parameters to the call in, say, the testfile test.lytex? I've been trying to add the --latex-program=pdflatex and the -o ./tmp options, but I just can't figure out how to do that. Thank you indeed for your work, though.

Comment: @SiskaÁdám: Which one?

Comment: Sorry, I just pressed enter while editing my question and it recorded my comment. I just wanted a line-break...

Comment: @SiskaÁdám: to (1) With the current version you have no choice. With version 4.0 (it's on the way) you can use `.araraconfig.yaml`. So it isn't visible. Maybe a standard search path should be `$TEXMF-HOME/scripts/arara/rules/`. I will discuss this. (2) additional information can be given by `% arara: lilypond: { format: pdflatex , output: ./tmp }` These options are provided in the rule.

Comment: Thank you for the help again. It seems that something is going then wrong here. What you suggested for (2) was my original guess, but it gives me an error: I'm sorry, but the flag set for the argument 'format' of the
'lilypond' task (referencing the 'lilypond.yaml' file located at
'/Users/sadam/Library/texmf/scripts/arara/rules') has an
unavailable variable/method in the rule context: 'latex'

Comment: @SiskaÁdám: If you run `lilypond-book --help` you will get `-f, --format=FORMAT  use output format FORMAT (texi [default], texi-html,latex, html, docbook)` So there is no `pdflatex`.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Actually, I don't need to set the format option, but the --latex-program to pdflatex (or, the --pdf flag).

Comment: Actually, is it feasible with arara to allow the user to enter any lilypond-book option without specifying them one-by-one in the rule?

Comment: @SiskaÁdám: You can add any options via the key `options`. Eg: `% arara: lilypond: { options: --here an option of lilypond }`

Comment: I see. Thank you. I am going to accept your answer, as it solves the original problem of running the two commands in one step. On the other hand, I still have a question, as the "output" option currently doesn't seem to work. The problem is, that the new .tex file is created within the temporal folder, so before running the `% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ test.tex ] }` line, the process should somehow move the generated .tex file to the main folder.

Comment: @SiskaÁdám: If you call  `% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ test.tex ] }` then the `tex` file must be located in the same folder. You can do: `% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ path/test.tex ] }`

Comment: Hi, that unfortunately gives an error, since pdflatex will not find the automatically generated files by lilypond-book (since pdflatex will still run in the parent folder). I realised that setting the TEXINPUTS macro before calling arara solves the problem. Unfortunately, I can't do that from TeXworks, at least I didn't find a solution to it. Another possibility would be if there was a rule in arara that I could use in order to move the resulting tex file one level higher, but I didn't find one yet.

Comment: @Marco: that's why you are the Cardinal Camerlengo of the Holy Bird. `:)` A possible workaround for the location problem would be a second rule called `move` which, well, moves the corresponding generated `.tex` file to the parent folder, and then `pdflatex` is invoked. Great answer, as usual. `:)`

Comment: In the meantime, I made an attempt to create a copy command, and succeeded! ;-) However, it turns out that it still doesn't solve the problem, as the lilypond-book generated automated latex file expects the garbage generated by lilypond-book to reside in the same folder as the tex source itself. The only solution that I can currently imagine would be if I could invoke pdflatex by arara from inside the temporal subfolder created by lilypond-book, which I'm not sure whether it was possible or not at all...

Comment: Here's my copy command (by cloning `clean`): `!config
# Copy rule for arara
# author: Ádám Siska
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: copy
name: CopyTool
command: <arara> @{copy} @{options} @{src} @{dst}
arguments:
- identifier: copy
  default: <arara> @{isWindows("cmd /c copy", "cp -f")}
- identifier: options
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
- identifier: src
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.src}
  default: <arara> .
- identifier: dst
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.dst}
  default: <arara> .`

Comment: OK, with the above `copy` command I was able to sort it out. Now I created an auxiliary tex file `thesis_main.tex`, which consists of `\usepackage{import}` and a subimport to the `thesis` file in the temporal folder. Then, I created an arara workflow of 10 steps in my original `lytex`: (1) `lilypond-book` (creates tmp folder) (2) `pdflatex` (on thesis_main) (3-6) rename the aux file, run `bibtex` and rename the resulting bbl and blg files back (7-8) `pdflatex`, two times (9-10) rename the pdf and clean. This way I end up having thesis.lytex, thesis.bib, thesis.pdf, thesis_main.tex; no garbage!

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Thank you again indeed for the very kind help, you saved my day with that script and with letting me know about this fascinating tool (arara).

Comment: @SiskaÁdám: Cool that everything works fine.