# Setting environment variable with arara

Tags: arara, texinputs

I wanted to set my `TEXINPUTS` environment variable from with an [`arara`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/arara/scripts/rules) rule/directive. For example my `texinputs.yaml` rule is

```
!config
identifier: texinputs
name: texinputs
command: export TEXINPUTS="@{mypaths}$TEXINPUTS:"
arguments:
- identifier: mypaths
  flag: "@{parameters.mypaths}"
```

and my `test.tex` file is

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
% arara: texinputs: { mypaths: ".//:" }
% arara: pdflatex
```

When I run `arara -v test` from the directory in which `test.tex` is located, I get

> Running texinputs...
>
> I'm sorry, but the command from the 'texinputs' task could not be
>   found. Are you sure the command 'export TEXINPUTS=".//:$TEXINPUTS:"'
>   is correct, or even accessible from the system path?

What am I doing wrong? I am on Linux with `TeX Live 2012`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I learned a lot in chat. Even if `texinputs.yaml` could be made to set the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable, this will have no affect on subsequent calls to the `pdflatex` directive since each directive runs in a self contained environment. The problem with `texinputs.yaml` as constructed is that in Linux `export` is a special commands built into the Bash shell and therefore "confuses" `arara` into thinking it is not a command.

The simplest, and possibly cleanest work around is to redefine the `pdflatex.yaml` rule to take a `texinputs` argument and then run `pdflatex` in `env` which allows setting of the environment variables. Specifically, the modified rule looks like

```
    !config
    # PDFLaTeX rule for arara
    # author: Marco Daniel
    # last edited by: Paulo Cereda
    # requires arara 3.0+
    identifier: pdflatex
    name: PDFLaTeX
    command: <arara> @{texinputs} pdflatex @{action} @{draft} @{shell} @{synctex} @{options} "@{file}"
    arguments:
    - identifier: action
      flag: <arara> --interaction=@{parameters.action}
    - identifier: shell
      flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.shell,"--shell-escape","--no-shell-escape")}
    - identifier: synctex
      flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.synctex,"--synctex=1","--synctex=0")}
    - identifier: draft
      flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.draft,"--draftmode")}
    - identifier: options
      flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
    - identifier: texinputs
      flag: "env TEXINPUTS=@{parameters.texinputs}"
```

There are at least two problems with this approach: it ignores previously set values of `TEXINPUTS` and cannot handle paths with spaces in them. It might be possible to work around both of these issues. A more general solution, but one that requires adding an additional script is to modify `pdflatex.yaml` to be

```
!config
# PDFLaTeX rule for arara
# author: Marco Daniel
# last edited by: Paulo Cereda
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: pdflatex
name: PDFLaTeX
commands:
- <arara> @{texinputs} '@{action} @{draft} @{shell} @{synctex} @{options} "@{file}"'
arguments:
- identifier: action
  flag: <arara> --interaction=@{parameters.action}
- identifier: shell
  flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.shell,"--shell-escape","--no-shell-escape")}
- identifier: synctex
  flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.synctex,"--synctex=1","--synctex=0")}
- identifier: draft
  flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.draft,"--draftmode")}
- identifier: options
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
- identifier: texinputs
  flag: texinputs.sh "@{parameters.texinputs}"
  default: pdflatex
```

and define a `texinputs.sh` file as

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
TEMP=$(echo $1 | sed s#\"##g)
export TEXINPUTS=$TEMP:$TEXINPUTS
pdflatex $2
```

This handles the appending of a preexisting `TEXINPUTS` as well as spaces in the path. I am hoping that there is a cleaner approach which handles a preexisting `TEXINPUTS` as well as spaces and doesn't require an `extra` script file.

Comment: `+1` Thank you very much for sharing this answer, Daniel! `:)`

Comment: `texinputs.sh` throws arguments `$3` and further arguments away. Also I would put `pdflatex` as argument to `texinputs.sh`. Then the line `pdflatex $2` can be replaced by the two lines `shift` and `"$@"`. And the call in the rule would be `@{texinputs} pdflatex @{action} @{draft} @{shell} @{synctex} @{options} "@{file}"`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek that is much better, I couldn't figure out how to deal with the quotes and hence my use of sed. That said, this just seems like a hacky way to work around to the checking that `arara` does for valid commands. I am not sure why from a design standpoint it is beneficial to prevent running shell built-in functions.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub: It is a good design choice of arara not to pass the command line to a shell. First there are many operating systems with many shells. Each shell has its own features of variable substitutions, embedded command calls, ... -- a nightmare for portability and security. The command and its arguments has to be written to a string and the string is parsed by the shell to get the arguments. Again a nightmare to get the spaces and the quoting right.

Comment: @StrongBad, Is there a way to do `export LC_ALL="en_US"` as a user command in TeXStudio? I need to be done before calling `LuaLaTeX`.