# I'm sorry but the file 'test.lytex' doesn't exist

Tags: arara, lilypond

I'm following a wonderful walk-through here in [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111055/how-to-run-latex-and-lilypond-book-in-one-command), as well as having RT[FM](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/support/arara/doc/arara-usermanual.pdf) (it really is fine), but am missing something.

Using OSX 10.10.5 - Yosemite. Latest version of TeXShop installed. TeX Live not complaining.

I have created an `araraconfig.yaml` file in my home directory:

```or-tag-here
ls -l ~/ | grep arara
-rw-r--r--    1 mikekilmer  staff   218B Jul 26 21:50 araraconfig.yml
```

It looks like this:

```
!config
# Config file to use texmfhome as search path
# # author: Marco Daniel
# # requires arara 3.0+
 paths:
 - /Users/mikekilmer/Library/texmf/scripts/arara/rules

 filetypes:
 - extension: lytex
   pattern: ^(\s)*%\s+
```

Inside of `/Users/mikekilmer/Library/texmf/scripts/arara/rules` there is the lilypond rule:

```
$ ls -l /Users/mikekilmer/Library/texmf/scripts/arara/rules
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 mikekilmer  staff   433B Jul 26 20:45 lilypond.yml
```

Content:

```
!config
# Mainfile rule for arara
# author: Marco Daniel
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: lilypond
name: Lilypond
command: <arara> lilypond-book @{format} @{options} @{output} "@{file}"
arguments:
- identifier: format
  flag: <arara> --format=@{parameters.latex-programm}
  default: <arara> --format=latex
- identifier: options
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
- identifier: output
  flag: <arara> --output=@{parameters.output}
```

And finally a test file:

```
% arara: lilypond
% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ test.tex ] }
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{lilypond}[staffsize=12]
\relative c' {
  c2^"Text" g'2 \times 2/3 { f8 e d } c'2 g4
}
\end{lilypond}
\end{document}
```

But:

```
$ arara test.lytex
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

I'm sorry, but the file 'test.lytex [.tex, .dtx, .ltx]' does not
exist. Note that when you provide only the basename (i.e, the
filename without the extension) or with an unknown extension,
arara will try to look for files ending with the predefined
extensions [.tex, .dtx, .ltx] in that order. You can override the
order, the search pattern or even add support for new extensions
through the configuration file. Please refer to the arara manual
to learn more about this feature.
```

Within directory I'm running command in:

```
$ ls -l | grep test
-rw-r--r--  1 mikekilmer  staff   231B Jul 26 21:52 test.lytex
-rw-r--r--  1 mikekilmer  staff   671B Jul 26 21:56 test.tex
```

Can anyone make a recommendation on further troubleshooting?

Comment: What is your source file actually called?

Comment: Hi @JosephWright - `test.lytex`

Comment: I'm pretty sure `arara` works on the basis the file _has_ to be of extension `.tex`, `.ltx` or `.dtx`, _i.e._ here it's looking for `test.lytex.tex`.

Comment: yes but I think adding `- extension: lytex` to the config file should allow `lytex`

Comment: Wondering if the config file isn't being read.

Comment: Interesting. I tried the very same scenario with TeX Live 2016 on Linux (Fedora 24) and Mac OS (El Captain) and everything worked fine. Mike, your setup is correct, there's no typo or wrong location as far as I can see at the moment. This might be tricky for us to debug, but let's go. `:)` Could you give me the output of `which -a arara`?

Comment: Oh my, I know what's going on! Ducks are very slow at spotting things, I am terribly sorry! `:)` You are using `.yml` as extension instead of `.yaml`, so `arara` is not finding your configuration file! Could you rename the extension of your YAML files to `.yaml`? I know `.yml` is quite used as well (specially for Ruby blokes), so it might be interesting for the next version to check that extension as well.

Comment: Wonderful news, dear man. Somehow the `a` in the extension was invisible to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer ended up being simply that as of `arara 3.0` the extension of the YAML file needs to be `.yaml` and not just `.yml`.

A way to test if your config file is being seen by Arara is simply to use some bad YAML syntax in it.

For example if you add the line:

```
x paths:
```

instead of `paths:`, then if Arara *is* seeing it, it will return an error:

```
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

I'm sorry, but apparently your arara configuration file is
invalid, that is, it has invalid or missing YAML entries.
Unfortunately, arara cannot proceed until the error is fixed. I
tried my best to dump the error message, so here it is:

Problem: Can't construct a java object for
tag:yaml.org,2002:com.github.arara.model.AraraConfiguration;
exception=Cannot create property=x paths for
JavaBean=com.github.arara.model.AraraConfiguration@27082746;
Unable to find property 'x paths' on class:
com.github.arara.model.AraraConfiguration
Error found in line 0, column 0.
    !config
```

If, for example, your file is named `araraconfig.yml` (as of arara 3.0), the error will not be returned because Arara is looking for a file with the `.yaml` extension.