# How would I make this image? (A type of music notation)

Tags: music

I was wondering if anyone knew how to make music notation that looks like the below: [image]

I'm not even sure where to start with this kind of thing, I've tried doing it by hand before in Inkscape, but I did not find that easy, algorithmic, or professional looking. I was hoping some kind of package might be available in TeX.

This is another, similar example:[image]

Comment: This looks like a strange hybrid between Western and Japanese musical notation.  (For a while I studied shakuhachi.)  You might look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/855/22413)

Comment: I've started looking at Lilypond... can I create things that aren't five line staves with it?

Comment: I've only dabbled with these packages just for fun and for only a bar or two for decorative effect in documents whose primary aim was not about music.  I can't really speak to the power of these packages other than I could recreate the first several bars from Mozart sonatas very nicely.

Comment: I have never used Lilypond, but I just looked at the examples and I believe both the three bar staff and your special tabulature would be supported.  http://www.lilypond.org/examples.html is the link.

Comment: @Anthony you must be patient with Lilypond, maybe you like Frescobaldi, is like a frontend for Lilypond. I found this guide for frescobaldi (in spanish) http://frescobaldi.org/uguide.es.html

Comment: For reference, this is called "tablature". In a guitar tabulature, which this resembles somewhat, the lines, instead of indicating pitches as in a normal staff, indicate strings on the instrument. So the notation shows not what pitches should sound but physically where the performer should place their fingers.

Answer (score 8):

For music, I only use [MusixTeX](http://www.mab.jpn.org/musictex/index_en.html), and I've try to make something like your kind of "triagram" on this package, and it seems to work...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\xil}[2]{\zchar{#1}{#2}\cl{*}}
\newcommand{\zil}[2]{\zchar{#1}{#2}}
\begin{music}
\parindent5mm
\setclef18
\setlines1{3}
\systemnumbers
\startpiece
\Notes\xil{3}{0}\xil{3}{2}\xil{7}{0}\xil{3}{0}\en
\bar
\Notes\xil{7}{3\#}\cl{*}\xil{7}{\large$\bullet$}\xil{7}{2}\en
\bar
\Notes\xil{7}{3\#}\en\notes\xil{7}{2}\xil{7}{2}\cl{*}\xil{3}{3\#}\cl{*}\en
\bar
\Notes\xil{3}{0}\cl{***}\en
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

I hope it'd be usefull!!