# Very short piece of music as high-res image

Tags: music

I am trying to include a very short piece of musical score (five line stave, 10 notes) into a document of mine. Unfortunately I only have a low-res image (see attached), which is not suitable for printing.

What's the best/quickest way to recreate that score in my article, short of having to learn and deal with MusicTeX, Lilypond or whatever else there might be out there? I am looking for a flat learning curve above all.

[image]

Comment: ... you sure you don't want to learn MusicTeX? Then the question doesn't really have much to do with this site, does it? — anyway, pick Encore or some GUI app to draw these things, screenshot at high resolution, then include as image should be reasonably good.

Comment: Yes, I'm positive that I don't want to learn MusicTeX at this point. That said, I am not a huge fan of „some GUI apps“. Luckily I have since found `abc` and are confident to be able to make it work.

Comment: Actually duplicate of [Can I create music sheets with LaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/855/can-i-create-music-sheets-with-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1) then, although there's no `abc` answer there. (I left a comment there too) you may want to post one there for completion if you know how to use it.

Comment: I am very much for looking up old answers … That said, > 11 years is a bit dated, even by TeX standards. I’ll post an answer, though, if I manage to come up with a good one.

Comment: Old answers are up-to-date or not depends on whether readers point out the errors when it becomes outdated or not...

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of how the code to the above excerpt might look in MusicTeX. You can include the produced pdf or directly use the code between `\begin{}` ... `\end{document}` in your file.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{musixtex}
\def\freqbarno{9999}

\begin{document}
\begin{music}
  \generalmeter{\meterfrac68}
  \startextract
  \NOTes \qlp{jl}\en\bar
  \Notes \qa{n} \cl{l}\en \Notes \qa{j} \cl{l}\en\bar
  \NOtes \qup{g} \qu{g} \cu{g}\en\bar
  \NOTEs \hlp{j}\en
  \setrightrepeat
 \endextract
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am afraid this *does* look more (powerful and thus) complex than the situation warrants right now. As I'll elaborate in my own answer below, I have found a solution with abc that fits my simple needs.

Comment: Comparing the output of all (at the time of this writing) three examples, your example looks best.  Elegant spacing and well proportioned line thicknesses, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this as an answer, since comments don’t allow for sufficient flexibility in formatting (and I have since found a good answer to my question).

The [ABC package](https://ctan.org/pkg/abc) allows for [music notation in the ABC format](https://abcnotation.com/) to be incorporated in your LaTeX files. Both the approach (adding another environment to you source file) and the notation are simple – the latter very much intentionally so: a bit like Markdown for Music, if you will :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abc}

\begin{document}
\begin{abc}
X:1
T:% Title left emptry
M:6/8
K:C treble
L: 1/8
| c3 e3 | g2 e1 c2 e1 | G3 G2 G | c6 z2 |]
\end{abc}
\end{document}
```

Notation should be pretty obvious when you compare to the final result:

[image]

Comment: Just one remark from a musician: please remove the bar before the first note, and your last measure is too full (you have inserted a rest instead of the repeat).